# I want only the array numbers to appear on the graphic

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a graph in python with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [256, 1024, 4096, 262144]
y = [0, 3, 40, 20843]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

That's the result:
[image]

But I want only the numbers in the array appear on the graphic. So, in the x axis only the numbers 0, 3, 40, 20843 appear and in the y axis only 256, 1024, 4096 and 262144.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.xticks()` and `.yticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html) functions to set the locations (and labels) of the x- and y-axis tick marks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [256, 1024, 4096, 262144]
y = [0, 3, 40, 20843]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.yticks(y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @jaryl It shows all of them, but the small ones are printing on top of one another because they are so close together. Space the points out more and you will see all of them. Otherwise, you should consider changing to a logarithmic scale to show the points over such a wide range of values.